# What do the columns in you get from iostat mean?

Tags: iostat

When I perform the command

> iostat -x | grep -P 'Device|x.\s'

I get the following columns as output

> device            rrqm/s    wrqm/s    r/s        w/s        rsec/s    wsec/s    avrq-sz    avqqu-s   await      svctm %util

What does each of these column mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know RTFM is not the answer you are looking for, but this time it is appropriate. Try `man iostat`, all the values are explained there. In case you are somehow missing the man pages, here's [a webified version](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iostat), although your Linux distribution might have a more current version of that man page.

Comment: +1, Most of the time "Read The Friendly Manual" isn't the best response; but sometimes people are just lazy, and lazy questions deserve lazy answers.

Comment: Agreed, and I couldn't explain the columns better than the man page, so linking to man page was a perfect answer this time. :-)

Comment: In my defense, I don't have a linux distribution and I just had to do a brief analysis of a log file that I got using iostat. I got my answer, so I cannot complain ;)

Answer (score 1):

see `man 1 iostat`. there is a list of all columns with explanations

http://linux.die.net/man/1/iostat